# Why does my pySerial data get corrupted mid-stream?

Tags: python, serial-port, embedded-linux, pyserial

This works wonderfully on Windows, with Python 3.10.  Incoming data has a delimiter, this delivers one message at a time, life is good...until I test on Linux.  Specifically Ubuntu 18.04.

On Linux, it receives a handful of messages successfully, and then it gets garbage, non-ascii values.  Oddly it often turns to garbage right after the delimeter, which seems like it is a hint, but I am not sure how.  I have tried changing the decode to 'utf-8', 'utf-16', and a variety of other things but observe the same behavior.

```
import serial, time
    incoming= ''
    delim = 'xyz'
    ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baud, timeout=timeout)
    while True:
        while ser.in_waiting > 0:
            incoming += ser.read(ser.in_waiting).decode('ascii')
            while delim in incoming:
                deliver, incoming = incoming.split(delim, 1)
                if deliver:
                    print(deliver)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Any suggestions on what the issue could be?

Comment: What makes you think it is a software problem?

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] your question and add some example of correct data and garbage? Please show them as hex bytes, not as characters. -- If you happen to have access to an oscilloscope, check the serial wire during the transmission.

Comment: @Lundin - works with the same cable on Windows.  There are several posts about reading files being "different" between Windows and Linux in Python, mostly due to default decoding, so I am hopeful.

Comment: @thebusybee - The best I can do is to offer one example of b'\x10A\x80\x84\x8c\x8c\xa5\xcb'.  Right-shifting those values does not produce a valid output (i.e. all chars <0x80, sensical) so it does not seem to be simply missing a bit.  A non-sensical version is \x04\x10\x60\x21\x23\x23\x29\x72, with valid values but they do not make sense for the application.  Closing the serial connection and reestablishing does resume valid input for a few messages until it becomes bad again.

Comment: As I kindly asked for, please extend your question by [edit]ing it. Comments are not for clarifications and additional information. They are often overlooked.

Comment: @thebusybee that would contain information that I cannot share.  But I found the problem, which I will post as an answer.  I wonder if it will surprise you as much as it did me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stty -F /dev/ttyUSBx`

This showed the serial settings, which identified that something is changing the BAUD rate.  When I printed `ser.baudrate` the Python indicates there is no change, but the above command showed the actual state of hardware and the problem is.

Now I need to figure out a way for the BAUD to not change...